# Changing all webpart's Zone ID on a Page programmatically

Tags: 2007, web-part, development

I Want to add all the webparts already exists on a Page with different zoneIDs into "Top" zone using c#.

I know i can use this code of line

```
SPLimitedWebPartManager wpManger = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("default.aspx", PersonalizationScope.Shared);
webpartdefault webpart = new webpartdefault(); 
 wpManger.AddWebPart(webpart, "Top", 1);
```

but thats when I add a webpart, But in my case all webparts are already there.

I tried this code, but it doesn't work as this property is read only

```
SPLimitedWebPartManager wpManger = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("default.aspx", 

            foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart eachwebpart in wpManger.WebParts)
             {
                 eachwebpart.AllowZoneChange = true;
                 eachwebpart.Zone = "Top";
                 wpManger.SaveChanges(eachwebpart);
             }
```

Ok guys, I made this code that actually works, but not for CreateModuleContent, and a list :/

```
protected void setCorrectView(SPWeb web)
        {
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            SPWebPartCollection wpcWebParts = web.GetWebPartCollection(PageUrl, Storage.Shared);
            foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart wptWebPart in wpcWebParts)
            {
                string titl = wptWebPart.Title;
                if (wptWebPart.ZoneID != "Top")
                {
                    wptWebPart.AllowZoneChange = true;
                    wptWebPart.ZoneID = "Top";
                    wpcWebParts.SaveChanges(wptWebPart.StorageKey);
                }
            }
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
```

Cheers

Comment: you can use powershell for that

Comment: I am making a Form Application that is doing many operations including this one, so that isn't the option here am afraid :S, thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [SPLimitedWebPartManager.MoveWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.splimitedwebpartmanager.movewebpart%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

And remember to call `wpManager.Web.Dispose();` even though you didn't allocate it

Comment: I just figured out that myself and was about to post the code but you already answered it , cheers :)